# Can I build a web app that allows Power BI Pro to connect using Organisation Account

Tags: powerbi

I am building a web app that connects to Power BI. Using the Power BI Pro desktop client, I see an option to connect to an OData Feed that supports authentication using "Organization account".

Can I build my web app to support such an auth flow? If so how?

P.S: My web app supports multi tenant Azure AD authentication.

Comment: Are you looking to embed the powerbi report into your web app?

Comment: Yes I am. Not sure how that is related though. I am looking at implementing a OData feed in my web app that will provide the data to Power BI. I consider it deal to have it authenticated using an Organisation account as opposed to an API key.